# Intersection of line with z-line

Tags: r, intersection, sf

I want to intersect a Z-line with a non-Z-line to obtain the intersection point with the z-value from the Z-line.

However, it doesn't work for these two lines:

```
my_line <- st_linestring(matrix(c(403606.39, 403601.85, 403601.09,
                                  5306798.72, 5306802.81, 5306803.73),
                                nrow = 3),
                         dim = "XY")

my_zline <- st_linestring(matrix(c(403601.81, 403601.85, 403602.26,
                                   5306802.76, 5306802.81, 5306803.48,
                                   241.61, 241.73, 242.98),
                                 nrow = 3),
                          dim = "XYZ")

st_intersection(my_line, my_zline)
```

Result, without the desired Z-coordinate:

```
POINT (403601.85 5306802.81)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With sf version 0.9.3 I see "POINT Z (403601.8 5306803 242.1067)". I assume the Z is interpolated but I'd do some more work to check. What's your `sf` version?

Comment: @Spacedman I just tried it with a different machine where sf 0.9-6 is installed and it worked! Also, during loading sf it said linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1...
I will update the packages on the machine where it didn't work tomorrow and try again. Thanks for your input

Comment: @Spacedman Indeed worked after I updated everything and I managed to get the same result as you. However, as the two lines have one point in comon - POINT Z (403601.85 5306802.81 241.73) - wouldn't you expect the intersection point to have exactly that Z?